# How do i change the value of input field as another input field is being updated? [HTML / JS]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 3 inputs fields in my HTML form. One of my input fields is disabled and the other two are working as normal. The two fields that are not disabled are supposed to fill in "parts" of the disabled one (so to put it simply - the two input fields values get combined into the disabled one)

How do I achieve this? Is there a way the value updates live as the user is typing into the enabled fields?

[image]

I tried this:

`

```
$('#productNameInput').keyup(function(e) {
    $("#productIDInput").html($(this).val());
}).keypress(function(e) {
    return /[a-z0-9.-]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

`

but everything is depreciated and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated - thanks :)

Comment: `$("#productIDInput").html` should be `$("#productIDInput").val(...)`

Comment: @Rajesh - thank you!!! i dont know how i missed that - works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Rajesh for pointing out my mistake: The code should be with . val, not .html -

```
$('#productNameInput').keyup(function(e) {
    $("#productIDInput").val($(this).val());
}).keypress(function(e) {
    return /[a-z0-9.-]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```